# how to optimize a select in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a mail_queue table in this table is all the emails that the system has to send and I use a CRON that runs this query every 5 minutes the select executed in PHP PDO, the select:

`"SELECT * FROM mail_queue WHERE sent_at IS NULL"`

I have more than 55 thousand records already executed the problem is that my website host notified me informing that this table is overloading the server and that I have to optimize or my account will be suspended I only know the basics of Mysql what ideas do you suggest to solve this problem?

I thought of creating a new table where I would leave only the records already sent and in the mail_queue table are only the emails that have not yet been sent, after the send function it saves this information in the new table and deletes these records from the mail_queue table , so this table never gets heavy. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Add this index `CREATE INDEX sent_at_idx ON mail_queue(sent_at)` if not added yet

Comment: It is not possible for a “table to be overloading a server”. I’m guessing that what’s happening is that the process you are running is overloading the compute/memory of the server. So you need to find out which process(es) are causing the issue - the select, the process that’s sending the emails, etc and then work from there

Answer (score 0):

You may go with two preferences, one is for optimization and the other is for segregation, either you may consider both or any one too:

1. **Indexing**: Ensure that appropriate indexes are set on the sent_at column in the mail_queue table. Indexing can significantly improve the performance of queries involving the sent_at column.
2. **Prioritization**: If possible, introduce a priority system for the emails in the mail_queue table. Assign priorities to different types of emails (e.g., high, medium, low), and modify your query to fetch and process emails based on their priority levels. This way, you can ensure that critical emails are processed first, reducing any potential delays.